# Blueimp File Upload - preview image pixelated

Tags: javascript, jquery, upload, image-uploading, blueimp

I'm using Blueimp File Upload on a .NET project with AMD/RequireJS. I'm currently only uploading images and would like a preview to be shown on the page before the image is uploaded. This is a native feature of the library and seems to be working okay.

The problem is that the preview image is always blurry/pixelated when I set the "previewMaxWidth" and "previewMaxHeight" options to anything over 80 pixels (the default). So, setting these 2 options to e.g. 220 pixels creates a 220 pixel Canvas but the image inside is pixelated, as if it was being scaled up from 80 pixels.

I couldn't find any similar issues here, but noticed the same behaviour occurs in the actual Blueimp demo pages if you change "previewMaxWidth" and "previewMaxHeight" to the same 220px I'm using.

**EDIT:** issue only applies to JPG images. PNG does not blur/pixelate.

Check [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDpGb.png) for a visual demo. Below is the my code:

```
$(config.browseButton).fileupload({
    url: "/myEndpointUrl.aspx",
    acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(jpe?g)$/i,
    maxFileSize: 5000000,
    previewMaxWidth: 220,
    previewMaxHeight: 220,
    previewCrop: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    autoUpload: false,
    disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/.test(window.navigator.userAgent)
}).on('fileuploadadd', function(e, data) {

    if (data.files && data.files[0]) {
        // Successfully injects the Canvas preview in the DOM
        config.elements.pictureHolder.html(data.files[0].preview);
    } else {
        console.log("No files have been selected");
    }

}).on('fileuploadprocessalways', function(e, data) {
    // ...
}).on('fileuploadprogressall', function(e, data) {
    // ...
}).on('fileuploaddone', function(e, data) {
    // ...
}).on('fileuploadfail', function(e, data) {
    // ...
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out all the images I was testing with had an EXIF thumbnail embedded as metadata, which Blueimp File Upload uses by default to preview the image on the browser, as opposed to loading and scaling down the actual main image.

There are two ways of avoiding this issue:

1) Remove the EXIF thumbnail from your file metadata using one of [these](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/3-ways-to-remove-exif-metadata-from-photos-and-why-you-might-want-to/) methods; you can often create a metadata-free copy of the image file by simple resaving it on Photoshop or similar.

or

2) Disable the use of the EXIF thumbnail by Blueimp; set the "disableExifThumbnail" option to false when you create your fileupload object:

```
$(config.browseButton).fileupload({
    ...
    previewMaxWidth: 220,
    previewMaxHeight: 220,
    ...
    disableExifThumbnail: true,
    ...
}).on('fileuploadadd', function(e, data) {
    ...
});
```